# Is recreating table/ keyspace with same name in Cassandra not good?

Tags: cassandra

I was going to a blog by Datastax which says it is not recommended to recreate table with same name. That is drop the table and create with the same name. Here is the link for Datastax [recreate table faq](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226339-FAQ-How-to-drop-and-recreate-a-table-in-Apache-Cassandra-versions-older-than-2-1).
It talks about jira ticket [CASSANDRA-5202](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CASSANDRA-5202). It was fixed in 2.1.

I have questions, I am on Cassandra 2.1.16

1. Is it safe to recreate table or keyspace with same name after dropping?
2. What precautions we must take if we recreate table or keyspace with same name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote that post 6 years ago. :)

As it clearly states, the problem existed in older versions of Cassandra. In C* 2.1 (and newer), a table ID (time UUID) is added to the table directory name on disk to prevent the problems I outlined in that post ([CASSANDRA-5202](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5202)). Cheers!